# Connect Firebase to custom domain - SSL issue

Tags: ssl, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to connect my firebase app to an **eHost** domain.
After all steps I can ser my app live and running, but only for a couple of hours then the **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** is shown.
After a meeting with eHost support they point out that the firebase SSL is the issue.
Is there a way around this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What URL is triggering that error message?

Comment: www.culturapp-bolivia.com

Comment: Forgot to tell that firebase provides with a SSL certificate and I bought an SSL certificate for he eHost site aswell.
Also eHost supports SNI technologies

Comment: Your domain had gotten into a bit of a weird state in our system. I'm reprovisioning it with a new cert now, it should hopefully be working in about an hour.

Comment: You sir make my day, thanks a lot :D

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I seem to be having the same issue however when I try to access my site it says the certificate is mismatched from: involveunation.com < that is not my site. my site is swiftacademy.io

Comment: @JamesG still having issues? swiftacademy.io is a green lock for me.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh thanks for the reply. All is OK. must have still been in some 'propagation' status or something. I appreciate you checking, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Facing the same issues for http://streetsofcalicut.com/ . Please assist . Thank you .

Comment: It'll be better to [reach out to support](https://firebase.google.com/support) for assistance.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh i am having the same problem with https://campsbayholidayhome.co.za/. Hosted with Google Firebase. How do i fix this?

Comment: Once more for emphasis: this issue is likely to go away on its own as sometimes DNS caching causes delays in certificate provisioning. If it's been multiple days (3+) the best thing to do is [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).